# MWS: ListPrice confusion

Tags: amazon-mws

I am really confused with one API result.

API Request: GetMatchingProductForIdRequest / IdType ASIN

Market: DE A1PA6795UKMFR9

ASIN: B001B603YU

API Response ListPrice: €81.99

Amazon URL: http://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B001B603YU

Price on Amazon: €44.17

Its the only product from a large list where the price doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood this API. `ListPrice` means RRP = recommended retail price (in German UVP = unverbindliche Preisempfehlung). This is not the price you can buy the product on amazon. See API call `GetCompetitivePricingForASIN` to get the prices you whant.
Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<GetCompetitivePricingForASINResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01">
<GetCompetitivePricingForASINResult ASIN="B001B603YU" status="Success">
  <Product xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01" xmlns:ns2="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01/default.xsd">
    <Identifiers>
      <MarketplaceASIN>
        <MarketplaceId>A1PA6795UKMFR9</MarketplaceId>
        <ASIN>B001B603YU</ASIN>
      </MarketplaceASIN>
    </Identifiers>
    <CompetitivePricing>
      <CompetitivePrices>
        <CompetitivePrice belongsToRequester="false" condition="New" subcondition="New">
          <CompetitivePriceId>1</CompetitivePriceId>
          <Price>
            <LandedPrice>
              <CurrencyCode>EUR</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>44.13</Amount>
            </LandedPrice>
            <ListingPrice>
              <CurrencyCode>EUR</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>44.13</Amount>
            </ListingPrice>
            <Shipping>
              <CurrencyCode>EUR</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>0.00</Amount>
            </Shipping>
          </Price>
        </CompetitivePrice>
      </CompetitivePrices>
      <NumberOfOfferListings>
        <OfferListingCount condition="Any">15</OfferListingCount>
        <OfferListingCount condition="New">15</OfferListingCount>
      </NumberOfOfferListings>
    </CompetitivePricing>
    <SalesRankings>
      <SalesRank>
        <ProductCategoryId>pet_products_display_on_website</ProductCategoryId>
        <Rank>21552</Rank>
      </SalesRank>
      <SalesRank>
        <ProductCategoryId>470605031</ProductCategoryId>
        <Rank>453</Rank>
      </SalesRank>
    </SalesRankings>
  </Product>
</GetCompetitivePricingForASINResult>
<ResponseMetadata>
  <RequestId>aa089a13374fcd2ad</RequestId>
</ResponseMetadata>
</GetCompetitivePricingForASINResponse>
```